# Creating a thumbnail grid with Singularty 1.x, second column lacks margins

Tags: sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

I'm trying to create a thumbnail grid with Singularity 1.x. Here's the code:

```
$cols:    3
$grids:   $cols
$gutters: 0.2

.element
  @for $i from 1 through $cols
    &:nth-child(#{$cols}n+#{$i})
      +grid-span(1,$i, $output-style: 'float')
```

The problem is that the second element (the one that receives `grid-span(1,2)`) lacks gutter (`margin-right`).

Screenshots:

- http://d.pr/i/Xsb7+
- http://d.pr/i/ZcMg+

I tried changing the number of columns `$cols`, and the result is the same: all elements receive correct margin, except for the second one.

How do make second element have correct margin just like the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an oversight in the Float output method. This will be fixed in 1.0.5

Comment: Singularity issue queue ticket for reference: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/88